# Getting HashMap values to a JSP page

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, hashmap

I'm using `Google translator API` to translate an uploaded text by the client. I have a dropdown to select the language. But I need its code to send it to the API. Therefore I used a `HashMap` inside a concrete java class as follows

countryCode.java

```
public class CountryCode {

    public Map getCountryList()
    {
        String fileName = "countryCode.txt";
        Map<String, String> code = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String line;
        BufferedReader fileReader = null;
        try {
            fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            try {
                while((line = fileReader.readLine())!= null)
                {
                    String[] mapPart = line.split(":", 2);
                    if(mapPart.length >= 2)
                    {
                        String key = mapPart[0];
                        String val = mapPart[1];
                        code.put(key, val);
                    }
                }
                fileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         for (String key : code.keySet())
            {
                System.out.println(key + ":" + code.get(key));
            }
        return code;
    }
}
```

this is my JSP page with the dropdown using Bootstrap

translation.jsp

```
<section class="bg-light-gray">
<div class="container">
    <form action="TextTranslation" method="post" class="form" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <div  id = "imageView" class="col-lg-8 center-block ">
            <div class="btn-group"> 
                <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select a Region <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <% 
        %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can't understand how to access hashmap values inside this dropdown.Do you have any idea?Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use scriplets you can use plain Java after using a jsp tag

```
<jsp:useBean id="myId" class="package.name.CountryCode"/>

<% 
    Map<String, String> myCode = myId.getCountryList();
    // do something with myCode
%>
```

If you are passing the map to the Jsp via a servlet you can simply store the map as an attribute and then access it via Expression Language

```
// within the Servlet you could set the attribute this way

Map<String, String> myCode = myId.getCountryList();
request.setAttribute("code", myCode);

// then within the Jsp you would access the map this way

${code.nameofyourfield}

// or

${code['nameofyourfield']}
```

Comment: how can I proceed after calling the getCountryList()?

Comment: After setting the variable within the tags you can use it on your Jsp page via Expression Language. I would not recommend using scriplets though. It is not considered good practice. Check out the answer by @Nicolas Filotto: that would be a good alternative.

Comment: can you provide me a sample code on how can i pass hashmap values to dropbox?

Comment: Pass values to dropbox? I based my answer on the code you posted. You need to refer to whatever API you are using for that.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. I was reffereing to dropdown.   ' <% 
             CountryCode x = new CountryCode();
            Map<String,String> codeMap = x.getCountryList();
           for(Map<String, String> map : codeMap)
           {
            
           }
            %>'. I tried this. But it gives an error

Comment: I don't think you can iterate through a map with a for loop and the syntax seems to be wrong anyway: you swapped item and collection...